# How to make a while loop run specific number of times only?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to push back only a certain number of words into a vector, but

```
while (cin >> words) {
        v1.push_back(words);
    }
```

loop doesn't end. The next statement is to convert everything into uppercase. But it won't get out of while loop. Continuosly keeps asking for new words to enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get hung up on doing everything at once. What you've just described is a `for` loop. Just read the input the number of times you need and `push_back()` with each iteration. When the `for` loop has reached the condition the loop ends as expected.

```
// Here I create a loop control (myInt), but it could be a variable
// from anywhere else in the code. Often it is helpful to ensure you'll 
// always have a non-negative number. This can done with the size_t type.
for(std::size_t myInt = 0; myInt < someCondition; ++myInt)
{
    // read the input
    // push it back
}
```

Remember C/C++ uses zero based containers when using for loops with the loop control as the index like => `myContainer[myInt]`.

Answer (score 0):

A neat way to do this would be to define a constant (*e.g.* `size_t const MAX_WORDS = 3;`) and check whether `v` has enough elements yet:

```
while ((v1.size() < MAX_WORDS) && (cin >> words))
{
    v1.push_back(words);
}
```